# Attempting to change the getter of an unconfigurable property

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Just making an app and got this error

```
App.js (647:882) Attempting to change the getter of an unconfigurable property.
Evaluating module://react-navigation.js
Evaluating module://App.js.js
Loading module://App.js
```

So, I think that it can be a version problem so I am giving the package.json code also.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "*",
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.3",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.2.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-navigation": "4.4.1",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "5.14.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "9.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "5.11.9",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "*",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons": "*",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "*",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "*"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having a version problem so instead of

```
"react-navigation": "4.4.1",
```

I have to use

```
"react-navigation": "4.2.0",
```